# How to initialise a method in a ruby class on rails server start up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created ruby thread which keep polling messages from Queue.
The following is the basic code block which keeps polling the queue infinitely.How could i initialise this method (poll method in class Poller ) on rails server start up  so that this code(infinite loop thread) block runs when the application starts

```
class Poller
 class << self
  def poll
    begin 
      ----polling logic for queue
      sleep(1.minute)
    end while(true)
  end

 end
end
```

How do i initialise above code  in a rails initialisers so that the above code will start polling messages from queue?

Comment: I have updated my question , hope it is better now

Comment: On a Rails production system, there are usually multiple server processes or threads per server and sometimes even multiple servers. Do you want to start just one `Poller` for all of them or one `Poller` each? How do you plan to restart the `Poller` when something goes wrong, by restarting the web server process? Is starting a `Poller` that only polls once in a Cron job that runs every minute an option? I would guess that is easier to setup, to manage and more reliable.

Comment: Its one Poller each server.how do i make above class start executing poll method on server start up? It should happen through my existing rails application and not any other way.

Comment: If i keep my file under Initializer folder , will rails fire poll method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call poll method from **initializers** and execute code.

Just create one .rb file in initializers and call poll method.